# Toggle role of a member

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So what I tried to do was, if the tagged user does not have the tagged role, the bot gives them the tagged role and if the tagged user already has the tagged role, the bot will remove it from them. But it keeps only giving the tagged user the role, even when the user has the role already.

```js
if (!member.roles.cache.has(role)) { 
  member.roles.add(role)
  message.channel.send(new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("RED")
    .setDescription(`${role} wurde ${member} hinzugefügt.`))

} else if (member.roles.cache.has(role)) { 
  member.roles.remove(role)
  message.channel.send(new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("RED")
    .setDescription(`${role} wurde von ${member} entfernt.`)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your `role` variable is a [`Role`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role) object (probably `message.mentions.roles.first()`).

As `member.roles.cache` is a collection, its [`has`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=has) method accepts an ID as the parameter. So try to check `if (member.roles.cache.has(role.id))`

Also, you should probably wait for the role to be added/removed before the confirmation message is sent. Check out the code below.

```js
if (member.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
  await member.roles.remove(role);

  return message.channel.send(
    new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('RED')
      .setDescription(`${role} wurde von ${member} entfernt.`),
  );
}

await member.roles.add(role);
message.channel.send(
  new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RED')
    .setDescription(`${role} wurde ${member} hinzugefügt.`),
);
```

<sub><sup>PS: make sure your handler is an async function, as I'm using `await` above.</sup></sub>